# Intermittent errors when performing export to file in Oracle 11g

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

**System info**
Oracle database 11g/11.2 Enterprise edition

**Summary**
When the procedure is called (via Hibernate's CallableStatements), it gets all the partitions to be exported based on the days to keep (an input parameter). After those partitions are evaluated, the function which accepts partitions lists as input parameters (the first one in the wall of code) uses the DBMS_DATAPUMP API to export the content into a flat file.
Sometimes (I don't have a 100% reproducible scenario) it fails with the error below. It has to be noted that 99.9% of the time these procedures run smootly. The database user has write access to the exports directory.

The procedure:

```
TYPE PARTITION_NAME_TYPE IS RECORD (
  PARTITION_NAME VARCHAR2(32)
);
TYPE PARTITION_LIST IS REF CURSOR RETURN PARTITION_NAME_TYPE;
PROCEDURE EXPORT_PARTITIONS (
P_TABLE_NAME          IN VARCHAR2,
P_PARTITION_LIST      IN PARTITION_LIST,
P_EXPORT_DIR          IN VARCHAR2,
P_PARALLELISM_DEGREE  IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
P_FILE_PATH           OUT VARCHAR2,
P_RESULT              OUT VARCHAR2,
P_RESULT_MSG          OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
V_PUMP_HANDLE           NUMBER; -- Data Pump job handle
V_PUMP_STATE            VARCHAR2(255);
V_PUMP_FILE             VARCHAR2(255);
V_PUMP_DIR              VARCHAR2(255);
V_JOB_STATE             VARCHAR2(4000);
V_STATUS                KU$_STATUS1010;
V_LOGS                  KU$_LOGENTRY1010;
V_ROW                   PLS_INTEGER;
V_ERRORDETAILS          VARCHAR2(4000);
V_PARTITION_LIST        VARCHAR2(32767);
V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP   PARTITION_NAME_TYPE;
BEGIN
FETCH P_PARTITION_LIST INTO  V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP;
IF P_PARTITION_LIST%NOTFOUND THEN
    P_RESULT := 'FAILED';
    P_RESULT_MSG := 'No partitions to export';
    RETURN;
END IF;
V_PARTITION_LIST := V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP.PARTITION_NAME;
V_PUMP_FILE := V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP.PARTITION_NAME;

LOOP
    FETCH P_PARTITION_LIST INTO  V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP;
    IF P_PARTITION_LIST%NOTFOUND THEN
        V_PUMP_FILE := V_PUMP_FILE || '_TO_' || V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP.PARTITION_NAME;
        EXIT;
    END IF;
    V_PARTITION_LIST := V_PARTITION_LIST || ',' || V_PARTITION_LIST_TEMP.PARTITION_NAME;
END LOOP;
V_PUMP_HANDLE := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT', 'TABLE');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(HANDLE => V_PUMP_HANDLE, FILENAME => V_PUMP_FILE || '.dbf' , DIRECTORY => P_EXPORT_DIR, FILETYPE => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(V_PUMP_HANDLE, V_PUMP_FILE || '.log',P_EXPORT_DIR, NULL, DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.DATA_FILTER (V_PUMP_HANDLE, 'PARTITION_LIST', V_PARTITION_LIST);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.SET_PARALLEL(V_PUMP_HANDLE, P_PARALLELISM_DEGREE);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB (V_PUMP_HANDLE);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.WAIT_FOR_JOB(V_PUMP_HANDLE, V_PUMP_STATE);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.DETACH(V_PUMP_HANDLE);
P_RESULT := 'SUCCESS';
-- get actual path to Export Directory
SELECT directory_path INTO V_PUMP_DIR FROM ALL_DIRECTORIES WHERE directory_name = P_EXPORT_DIR;
P_FILE_PATH := V_PUMP_DIR || '/' || V_PUMP_FILE || '.dbf';
P_RESULT_MSG := 'Successfully exported ' || P_TABLE_NAME || '(' || V_PARTITION_LIST || ') as ' || V_PUMP_FILE || '.dbf';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUS(V_PUMP_HANDLE, 8, 0, V_JOB_STATE, V_STATUS);
  V_LOGS := V_STATUS.ERROR;
  V_ROW := V_LOGS.FIRST;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN V_ROW IS NULL;
    V_ERRORDETAILS := 'LOGLINENUMBER='||V_LOGS(V_ROW).LOGLINENUMBER || '   ERRORNUMBER='||V_LOGS(V_ROW).ERRORNUMBER || ' LOGTEXT='||V_LOGS(V_ROW).LOGTEXT;
    V_ROW := V_LOGS.NEXT (V_ROW);
  END LOOP;
  P_RESULT_MSG := 'Failed to export partitions on ' || P_TABLE_NAME || '(' || V_PARTITION_LIST || ') : ' || SQLERRM || ' Details: (' || V_ERRORDETAILS || ')';
  P_RESULT := 'FAILED';
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.STOP_JOB(V_PUMP_HANDLE);
END EXPORT_PARTITIONS;

PROCEDURE EXPORT_PARTITIONS (
P_TABLE_NAME          IN VARCHAR2,
P_NUM_DAYS_TO_KEEP    IN NUMBER,
P_EXPORT_DIR          IN VARCHAR2,
P_PARALLELISM_DEGREE  IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
P_FILE_PATH           OUT VARCHAR2,
P_RESULT              OUT VARCHAR2,
P_RESULT_MSG          OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  V_MIN_DAYS_TO_KEEP NUMBER := 1;
  V_CNT              NUMBER;  
  V_PARTITIONS       PARTITION_LIST;
  V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT VARCHAR2(2000);
  V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT_MSG VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  IF P_NUM_DAYS_TO_KEEP < V_MIN_DAYS_TO_KEEP THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot drop partitions less than ' || V_MIN_DAYS_TO_KEEP || ' days old.');
  END IF;
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO V_CNT
  FROM USER_TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = P_TABLE_NAME;
  IF V_CNT         = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Table Does Not Exist');
  END IF;
  OPEN V_PARTITIONS FOR SELECT partition_name
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
  WHERE table_name = UPPER(P_TABLE_NAME)
  AND
    CASE
      WHEN INSTR(PARTITION_NAME, 'MAXVALUE') = 0
      THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PARTITION_NAME, -8), 'YYYYMMDD')
    END < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - P_NUM_DAYS_TO_KEEP
  ORDER BY partition_name ASC;
  EXPORT_PARTITIONS(P_TABLE_NAME, V_PARTITIONS, P_EXPORT_DIR, P_PARALLELISM_DEGREE, P_FILE_PATH, V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT, V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT_MSG);
  CLOSE V_PARTITIONS;
  IF INSTR(V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT, 'SUCCESS') = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cannot export partitions. Logs purging will not proceede. ' || V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT_MSG);
  END IF;
  P_RESULT := 'SUCCESS';
  P_RESULT_MSG := V_EXPORT_PARTITIONS_RESULT_MSG;    
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  P_RESULT_MSG   := 'Failed To Export Partition on ' || P_TABLE_NAME || ': ' || SQLERRM;
  P_RESULT := 'FAILED';
END EXPORT_PARTITIONS;
```

The error:
    ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
    ORA-06512: at * . *, line 208
    ORA-39001: invalid argument value

What's on line 208 can be found below:

```
SQL> select text from all_source where type = 'PACKAGE BODY' and owner = '***' and name = '***' and line = '208';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  P_RESULT_MSG := 'Failed to export partitions on ' || P_TABLE_NAME || '('                   || V_
  PARTITION_LIST || ') : ' || SQLERRM || ' Details: (' || V_ERRORDETAILS || ')';
```

After busting my head around for several days, I still haven't managed to find the problematic piece of code.

**Edit #1**
The caller of the procedure is a Hibernate CallableStatement. The declaration of the resultMsg on the java side is as follows:

```
call.registerOutParameter("resultMsg", Types.VARCHAR);
```

This calls the `EXPORT_PARTITIONS(tableName, daysToKeep, exportDir, paralelismDegree)` procedure, which then calls the second `EXPORT_PARTITIONS` procedure.

Comment: You are potentially building quite a long error message. How is `p_error_msg` defined by the *caller* of this procedure? That seems to be too small - not so much a problem with the code you showed. You must be getting an actual exception from the export, but you don't see it because you're catching it and then failing to pass it back to the caller as a message.

Comment: Edited original post to include more information about the call sequence.

Comment: OK, but with a large enough list of partitions you could still be trying to exceed 32k; which might itself be what's causing the original exception, if it's trying to append so many partition names that `v_partition_names` itself tries to exceed 32k. You need to add some debugging, maybe starting with displaying the sizes and values of the components that are trying to create \p_error_msg\ before it actually hits line 208.

Comment: That would require ~1200 partitions to be exported at once, which is not likely at all. Also, I was thinking of implementing an exception handling which cuts the parsing of the partitions when exceeding the size of the variable and then do it in batches.